# How can I sync data between Scrapy Parse Methods without using "meta"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to use some other approach than using meta because meta is currently used to handle 302 response in my spider. When I add extra Items in this dictionary, to sync data, 302 response is ignored

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in urls:
            self.rowExt = row
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True,
                meta={
                    'dont_redirect': True,
                    'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                }
            )
```

if I add any extra item to this dictionary, 302 response handling doesn't work.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in urls:
            self.rowExt = row
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True,
                meta={
                    'dont_redirect': True,
                    'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                    'Name': name,
                    'Price': price,
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Scrapy v1.7+ you can use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb_kwargs#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs), the use is somewhat similar.

```
    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True,
        meta={
            'dont_redirect': True,
            'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
        },
        cb_kwargs={
            'name': name,
            'price': price,
        }
    )

    def parse(self, response, name, price):
        ....
```

Notice that the items passed into `cb_kwargs` are passed into the callback function as keyword arguments, so you need to adjust the function signature accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, if my answer solved the issue, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Definitely worth remembering that point about being passed in the callback function as keyword arguments. That gets missed when you read about it in the docs.